# Ample free time

Tags: team-management, motivation, team-building

I'm handling a Production support team. How to keep the team motivated and busy when the daily 'Business As Usual's are mostly automated and the team requires 2-3 hours in the day to complete the manual work? The management team doesn't want to shuffle/reduce the team, anticipating a new project will be live in the near future (maybe 1-2 months).

The team already has done a few proof of concepts and obtained new learnings on the technical and process side. They also help the other teams whenever required.

The question is: how to engage the team and make ideal use of the free time?

Comment: Are you really saying that there are zero opportunities for continuous process improvement, teaming, or servicing of tech debt? Or are you trying to crowd-source ideas? If the latter, this question is off-topic as a list-generating question.

Comment: The main problem is the team is completely demotivated due to the wrong commitments/promises from the management about the new opportunities.
I'm just looking for motivating the team and use the free time which the team has now.

Answer (score 5):

> How to keep the team **motivated**

Ask the team.

Chances are, the team knows both:

- What they want to do
- What improvements to their process would help most

...far better than you (or, most *certainly*, strangers on the internet) ever could.

So ask them, discuss, and then ensure they're empowered to actually carry it out.

Comment: I'd only add that keeping them *busy* for the sake itself is probably a utilization fallacy. Otherwise, great answer. +1

Comment: Due to the high level of demotivation and wrong/false commitments from management (always), the team is not ready to open up.

Comment: @DJo Well, now you know what improvement to their process would help most - regain their trust. The *how* is the hard part, and easily its own separate Question.

Answer (score 1):

Things I've done in the past:

- Talk to people separately, if I see their motivation is down - try to find out what worries them, what would make them happy, etc.
- Go the "official" route: get them to talk in the retrospective or 1 on 1 meetings (as a line manager).
- Haul a bunch of people to Oliver's (the next door pub) and get them some beers - usually helps (I'm kind of joking, but kind of not ;))
- organize any number of small scale events that don't need much budget or hassle: table tennis tournament, pot-luck lunches, board game Fridays, etc. People pick that up rather quickly and it creates some good energy.

In general I would encourage people to work on personal development in their "downtime" - take a course on Udemy/Coursera, pick up creative writing or whatever gets their juices flowing.